# Combine PDFs c#

Tags: c#, pdf-generation

How can I combine multiple PDFs into one PDF without a 3rd party component?

Answer (score 21):

I don't think you can.
Opensource component PDFSharp has that functionality, and a nice [source code sample on file combining](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=24&Itemid=35)

Comment: I know this is old, but I followed this answer and discovered that PDFSharp still hasn't implemented support for the more modern versions of PDF... you may need to jump through hoops to get it to work for all PDFs.  See this before jumping in: http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=693

Answer (score 5):

The .NET Framework does not contain the ability to modify/create PDFs. You need a 3rd party component to accomplish what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, there is nothing built in to do that task. Use [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/) with this [example code](http://www.steedsoft.com/itextsharp/tutorial01/ap01Concat.cs.html).

Comment: I think someone should always make the note that iTextSharp uses the AGPL license, which requires you to release your source code along with documenting iTextSharps usage appropriately.  They do have commercial licensing available, though. Be careful how you use it!

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK C# has no built-in support for handling PDF so what you are asking can not be done without using a 3rd party component or a COTS library.

Regarding libraries there is a myriad of possibilities. Just to point a few:

http://csharp-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/giospdfnetlibrary.aspx

http://www.pdftron.com/net/index.html

Answer (score 3):

I don't think  .NET Framework contains such like libraries.  I used iTextsharp with c# to combine pdf files. I think iTextsharp is easyest way to do this. Here is  the code I used.

```
string[] lstFiles=new string[3];
    lstFiles[0]=@"C:/pdf/1.pdf";
    lstFiles[1]=@"C:/pdf/2.pdf";
    lstFiles[2]=@"C:/pdf/3.pdf";

    PdfReader reader = null;
    Document sourceDocument = null;
    PdfCopy pdfCopyProvider = null;
    PdfImportedPage importedPage;
    string outputPdfPath=@"C:/pdf/new.pdf";


    sourceDocument = new Document();
    pdfCopyProvider = new PdfCopy(sourceDocument, new System.IO.FileStream(outputPdfPath, System.IO.FileMode.Create));

    //Open the output file
    sourceDocument.Open();

    try
    {
        //Loop through the files list
        for (int f = 0; f < lstFiles.Length-1; f++)
        {
            int pages =get_pageCcount(lstFiles[f]);

            reader = new PdfReader(lstFiles[f]);
            //Add pages of current file
            for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
            {
                importedPage = pdfCopyProvider.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                pdfCopyProvider.AddPage(importedPage);
            }

            reader.Close();
         }
        //At the end save the output file
        sourceDocument.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }


private int get_pageCcount(string file)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(file)))
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"/Type\s*/Page[^s]");
        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(sr.ReadToEnd());

        return matches.Count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this correct or helpful please accept the answer

Comment: Thank you! Last minute save when I needed it. it is fast as well!

Answer (score -1):

Although it has already been said, you can't manipulate PDFs with the built-in libraries of the .NET Framework.  I can however recommend [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/), which is a .NET port of the Java iText.  I have played around with it, and found it to be a very easy tool to use.

Answer (score -1):

[ITextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/) is the way to go