# How can I render a report as a PDF with different page orientation, and include headers/footers for subreports? SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Working with Reporting Services 2008 r2.

So here's my issue:

We have 5 reports that need to be combined into an "All Reports" report, which was originally done using VB6.

I created a master report with 5 subreports, and of course, it doesn't work.

**I need to get certain reports to render as landscape, and others as portrait. Also, I want to get the headers and footers from each of the subreports.**

***I know that SSRS doesn't support either of these***, but is there a way to "pre-render" the subreports as PDF, and then combine them into one PDF via reporting services?

Comment: +1 interesting question. AFAIK this can't be done with just SSRS, I think [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73950/combine-pdfs-c-sharp) will be your best bet for merging PDF's. Hoping someone else can show us otherwise though.

Comment: Looks like this is the only way. Though I might have to do this in VB6.

Comment: VB6? Oi oi, ["released 21 years ago"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VB6). You could try implementing [IRenderingExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154018) and do things in VB.NET or C#...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done out of the box. The only way you're going to accomplish this is through custom code. There are tools out there that you can build/buy to merge your PDFs into a single document. I can't comment on which tool is the best approach, but I can tell you custom code is the only approach.

Comment: This is pretty much the answer. Though I need something that can take in 5 Reporting service links (that generate the PDFs) and then combine them into one PDF. As a link in an ASP application with VB6 underlying code.

:(

Comment: If that's your ultimate goal, and if you're going to have to write code, consider writing code that generates RDL on the fly. I just did something similar where I start with a template report, and then use Linq to XML to pull things out of the template and add other things in. Then use the Web service to call the Render method on the final document with the PDF output format.