# How to convert a multi-page PDF to single-page Tiff, by page using C#

Tags: c#, pdf, report, render, tiff

This is my first post, sorry for my little miss.

I wanna convert a multi-page PDF to single-page Tiff.
I searched it and found many solutions, but all solutions use some DLL.
I don't wanna use DLL(third parties).
Do you have a solution? Please tell me.

What I want to do:
1. Report file render to PDF file.
2.Multi-page PDF convert to single-page PDF(or image?) file.
3.Single-page PDF convert to single-page Tiff file.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73950/combine-pdfs-c-sharp

Comment: @Fabien Thank you!! :)